# how to pattern match first character in string

Tags: scala, recursion, pattern-matching

I'm just learning scala, and working through the advent of code as exercises. I know that pattern matching is popular in Haskell, and hoping to do similarly in scala.

```
def part1(visited: Set[Coord], current: Coord, directions: String):  Set[Coord] = directions match {
  case "^" :: tail => part1(visited + current, current.up, tail)
  case "v" :: tail => part1(visited + current, current.down, tail)
  case "<" :: tail => part1(visited + current, current.left, tail)
  case ">" :: tail => part1(visited + current, current.right, tail)
  case _ => visited + current // The string is empty
}
```

I've tried converting using an Array or List of characters instead of a string, but keep getting stuck. The code I pasted above reports:

```
Day3.scala:8: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
 required: Array[Char]
    case '^' :: tail => part1(visited + current, current.up, tail)
             ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::`, also known as Cons, is a constructor for `List` which has a head and a tail. You have an `Array[Char]` representing the String, so you can't use List semantics unless you explicitly convert to a `List[Char]`. What you can do is use a guard:

```
def part1(visited: Set[Coord], current: Coord, directions: String):  Set[Coord] = 
  directions match {
    case x if x.startsWith("^") => part1(visited + current, current.up, x.tail)
    case x if x.startsWith("v") => part1(visited + current, current.down, x.tail)
    case x if x.startsWith("<") => part1(visited + current, current.left, x.tail)
    case x if x.startsWith(">") => part1(visited + current, current.right, x.tail)
    case _ => visited + current // The string is empty
}
```

Note `tail` comes from `IndexedSeqOptimized`, not directly from `String`.

Answer (score 1):

`::` is only defined for lists, and while `String`s can be implicitly converted to `Seq`, the result isn't a `List` - you can use `toList` to convert the `Seq` into a `List`. Also, use single quote to create a `Char` and not a String:

```
directions.toList match {
  case '^' :: tail => // ...
  case 'v' :: tail => // ...
  case '<' :: tail => // ...
  case '>' :: tail => // ...
  case _ => // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can match on the result of `headOption` (return the first character, or `None`) only:

```
directions.headOption match {
  case Some('^') => // ...
  case Some('v') => // ...
  case Some('<') => // ...
  case Some('>') => // ...
  case _ => // ...
}
```

Comment: First example forces him to concat `tail` back to a `String` as he now has a `List[Char]` for tail.

Comment: Good point, I completely ignored the actual code in the cases... :|

Comment: I've taken basically your first suggestion, but I converted direction to a List[Char] before even starting the recursion, and updated the signature accordingly. But still getting: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;